# How to add additional custom field in streaming event payload?

Tags: platform-event, streaming-api, event-monitoring

We have enabled streaming events and are able to publish event streams to consumers. We would like to also include a custom field with each platform event published that would hold the org ID.

For example we have enabled Login Event (/event/LoginEVentStream) and while the consumers are able to see the event payload, we would also like to include a custom field that holds the org ID.

Any tips on how one can accomplish that?

Comment: You can't modify the OOTB Event Log Monitoring sobjects

Comment: You can derive it from your subscriber's connection.  For some events, you can also use `LoginUrl` and/or `NetworkId`.